Do all Brauer relations for finite groups vanish under the augmentation map?
The Burnside ring $B(G)$ of a finite group $G$ is the ring of all finite $G$-sets under disjoint union and Cartesian product. It is well known that $\mathbb{Q} \otimes B(G)$ has as basis $\{[G/H] \mid H \le_G G \}$ ($\le_G$ means $H$ is taken up to $G$-conjugacy) and there is a natural surjection $\theta$ onto the representation ring $\mathbb{Q} \otimes R(G)$ which has basis the images of $\{[G/H] \mid H \le_G G, \mbox{ $H$ cyclic } \}$. The kernel $ker(\theta)$ is called the set $K(G)$ of Brauer relations. For example, if $G=S_3$, $K(G)$ is generated by a single relation $$[G/\langle () \rangle]-2[G/\langle (1,2) \rangle]-[G/\langle (1,2,3) \rangle]+2[G/G].$$
Observe that applying the augmentation map $\epsilon: [G/H] \mapsto 1$ to this relation gives $1-2-1+2=0$. More generally I have checked that all relations of all groups $G$ with $|G| \le 63$ vanish under $\epsilon$. Is this true in general?

Yes, because $\epsilon$ is equal to the composition of $\theta$ with the map $\mathbb Q\otimes R(G)\to \mathbb Q$ sending the trivial representation to $1$ and all nontrivial irreducible representations to $0$. Since Brauer relations are sent to zero by $\theta$ they are sent to $0$ by $\epsilon$.
To check this, we just need to observe that the representation associated $[G/H]$ is the sum of the one-dimensional trivial representation with some nontrivial irreducible representations. By semismiplicity, we need to check that the $G$-invariants of this representation are one-dimensional, which is clear as any $G$-invariant function on $G/H$ must be constant.

Put another way, (implicitly using Frobenius reciprocity), the augmentation map as you define it counts the multiplicity of the trivial character in the virtual permutation character naturally associated to a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of transitive $G$-sets. On the other hand, if that combination of $G$-sets is sent to zero in the representation ring, its (virtual) character is clearly the zero character, so the trivial character obviously occurs with multiplicity zero. ( Well, I am working integrally here, but the argument adapts to $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations).
